# Integral for Bhattacharyya distance between two Cauchy distributions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, distributions

I need to perform the following integral to calculate the Bhattacharyya distance between two Cauchy distributions:

$$
I = \frac{\sqrt{b_+ b_-}}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left[(x-1)^2+b_+^2\right]\left[(x+1)^2+b_-^2\right]}}
$$

Here, $b_+ >0$, $b_->0$, and $b_+ \neq b_-$. The case $b_+ = b_-$ is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616995/challenging-integral-with-root-in-denominator).

I saw on [another forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243943/is-it-correct-to-compute-bhattacharyya-distance-for-cauchy-like-bell-shaped-fun) that Maple can apparently express this integral in terms for Elliptic functions. But the user displayed their answer in a form that is completely unreadable. I don't have access to Maple, so I tried reproducing the result with Mathematica 12.1 but it seems incapable to find an answer.

Anyone know how I can help Mathematica do this? The code that is not sufficient is:

```
int = (Sqrt[bp bm]/Pi) Integrate[1/Sqrt[((x - 1)^2 + bp^2) ((x + 1)^2 + bm^2)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {bp > 0, bm > 0}]
```

Comment: With **Maple** I have: `(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bm bp]
  EllipticK[(2 (bm^4 - 2 bm^2 (-4 + bp^2) + (4 + bp^2)^2))/(
  bm^4 - 2 bm^2 (-4 + bp^2) + (4 + bp^2)^2 + (4 + bm^2 + bp^2) Sqrt[
    bm^4 - 2 bm^2 (-4 + bp^2) + (4 + bp^2)^2])])/(Sqrt[
 4 + bm^2 + bp^2 + Sqrt[
  bm^4 - 2 bm^2 (-4 + bp^2) + (4 + bp^2)^2]] \[Pi])`

Comment: I confirm that it works numerically. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I massaged the answer given by Mariusz in the comments. For future reference, the answer is:

$$I = \frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{b_+ b_-}{A_+}} K\left(\frac{A_-}{A_+}\right).$$

Here, I have introduced:

$$A_\pm = 4 + (b_+ \pm b_-)^2,$$

and $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind as defined by Mathematica's `EllipticK[]`.

Edit: I have incorporated Andrea's further simplifications.

Edit: This is also the result for the Chernoff distance between the two Cauchy distributions. This follows from the fact that the [KL distance is symmetric](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10965) in that case.

Edit: Since then, I have found that this result can now be found in a slightly different form [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.12459).

Comment: you could complete simplification with `((4*Sqrt[bm*bp])/(Sqrt[ap]*Pi))*EllipticK[am/ap]`

Comment: I checked it numerically and I don't think it gives the right result? There might be other simplifications though.

Comment: `{((4*Sqrt[bp*bm])/(Pi*(Sqrt[ap] - Sqrt[am])))*
         EllipticK[4/(2 - Sqrt[ap/am] - Sqrt[am/ap])] /. {ap -> 
     4 + (bp + bm)^2, 
         am -> 4 + (bp - bm)^2}, ((4*Sqrt[bm*bp])/(Sqrt[ap]*Pi))*
    EllipticK[am/ap] /. 
       {ap -> 4 + (bp + bm)^2, am -> 4 + (bp - bm)^2}} /. {bp -> 0.7, 
  bm -> 0.3}`

Comment: You're correct, it works. I had made a mistake. I will change it.